# Creating a simple binary search function in Python

Tags: python, binary-search

Based on a LeetCode problem solution, I am practicing making binary search algorithms. I wrote this below, using a mix of the code from the LeetCode solution, and new code. Upon running, it fails to print the final string as is expected.

edit: I forgot to mention that, other than not printing to console, the code executes fine, in an expected amount of time, with no errors.

The binary_search_func uses almost the same exact code as the LeetCode problem, with the addition of the counter.

My best guess is it's a problem with the While loop condition, though when I changed it to While True, with 'break' as part of the if statement for guess(mid) == 0, it didn't work at all.

Here is the code:

```
target = int(input("Enter the target value.\n"))
maximum = int(input("Now, enter maximum value, for range of search.\n"))

def binary_search_func(n):
    """Search for a specific value within a range of 1 to n."""    

    low = 1
    high = n
    count = 1
    
    while low <= high:
        mid = int(low + (high - low) / 2)

        if guess(mid) == 0:
            print(f"Found {mid}, taking {count} turns.")
        
        elif guess(mid) == 1:
            low = mid + 1
            
        elif guess(mid) == -1:
            high = mid - 1
        
        count += 1


def guess(num):
    """Return value, depending upon whether guessed val == target val."""

    if num == target:
        return 0

    elif num > target:
        return 1

    elif num < target:
        return -1

binary_search_func(maximum)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to the wrong side of the binary range. You should look at the right when `guess` returns -1 and vice versa.

Secondly, when you have a match, you should exit the loop, or it will go on infinitely.

```
if guess(mid) == 0:
    print(f"Found {mid}, taking {count} turns.")
    break  # add this
elif guess(mid) == -1:  # corrected
    low = mid + 1
elif guess(mid) == 1:   # corrected
    high = mid - 1
```

Actually you don't need the last block of the `if` to be an `elif`, as it is the only possibility that is left. It can just be an `else`.

Answer (score -2):

Try this code:

```
# Returns index of x in arr if present, else -1 
def binary_search(arr, low, high, x): 
  
    # Check base case 
    if high >= low: 
  
        mid = (high + low) // 2
  
        # If element is present at the middle itself 
        if arr[mid] == x: 
            return mid 
  
        # If element is smaller than mid, then it can only 
        # be present in left subarray 
        elif arr[mid] > x: 
            return binary_search(arr, low, mid - 1, x) 
  
        # Else the element can only be present in right subarray 
        else: 
            return binary_search(arr, mid + 1, high, x) 
  
    else: 
        # Element is not present in the array 
        return -1
  
# Test array 
arr = [ 2, 3, 4, 10, 40 ] 
x = 10
  
# Function call 
result = binary_search(arr, 0, len(arr)-1, x) 
  
if result != -1: 
    print("Element is present at index", str(result)) 
else: 
    print("Element is not present in array")
```

Comment: The OP already knows about working versions (as explained in their question). They are looking for the error in their code. So "try this" is not helpful